# Cannot sign swidtag file with DigiCert Cloud HSM private key

Tags: code-signing, installshield, hardware-security-module

I purchased a code sign certificate from DigiCert and it uses Cloud HSM private key.

Then I call smksp_cert_sync to sync the certificate to local store.

Then I set in InstallShield project to use the certificate to sign.

The sign is OK for all other files, except for swidtag file, as below:

```
ISDEV : error -1027: Failed signing regid.2006-01.com.datanumen_A08C9017-1BA0-4E7F-8CFD-8076612DA796.swidtag
```

So, can swidtag file be signed with  DigiCert Cloud HSM private key?

I am using InstallShield 2020 R2